# libmemcached - checking if I'm connected

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

Is there an easy way to check if a given `memcached_st*` is successfully connected to a memcached server?

I'm connecting via `memcached_server_add_with_weight`, and it's returning `MEMCACHED_SUCCESS` when I give it spurious hostnames. Similarly, calling `memcached_last_error_errno` immediately after the call to `memcached_server_add_with_weight` gives me `MEMCACHED_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting way to do this is checking the actual socket descriptor.
If libmemcached successfully connected to the server then the socket descriptor is positive, otherwise it is -1.

```
std::shared_ptr<memcached_st> es (memcached_create (NULL), [](memcached_st* msp) {memcached_free (msp);});
memcached_server_add_with_weight (es.get(), "server1", 9201, 100);
memcached_server_add (es.get(), "server2", 9201);
memcached_server_add (es.get(), "server3", 9201);
memcached_server_fn serverVisitor = [](const memcached_st *ptr, memcached_server_instance_st server, void *context) {
  if (server->fd < 0) throw std::runtime_error (std::string ("libmemcached connection to ") + server->hostname + " failed!");
  return MEMCACHED_SUCCESS;
};
memcached_server_cursor (es.get(), &serverVisitor, NULL, 1);
```